# Посоветуйте плагин для вставки google maps

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка, google-maps-api

Всем доброго времени суток, посоветуйте пожалуйста то ли какой нибудь удобный плагин (то ли способ) для интегрирования карт (желательно Google maps). Сейчас делаю карту с использование yandex api так как там все в целом проще, в то время как для использования google api требуется использовать какой то ключ.

Чтобы лишний раз не давать вам повода для недоумивания (может я не верно сформулировал сам вопрос) скажу честно с javascript дружу очень плохо.

Comment: для гугл мапс в любом случае нужен будет апи ключ, но получить его элементарно в консоли разработчика https://console.developers.google.com/?hl=ru

Answer (score 3):

Рекмендую одну небольшую и простую библиотеку для работы с гугл картами gmaps.js

```js
var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat:  55.7522200,
    lng: 37.6155600
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/HPNeo/gmaps/master/gmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

[gmaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/)

[как получить api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key?hl=ru)

Answer (score 1):

Согласно **[документации Гугл](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update)**: после 12 октября 2016 года, реализации приложений с использованием ***[API Карт JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)***, ***[API статических карт](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/)***, или ***[Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/)*** не может превышать **25000** загрузок карты в сутки - бесплатно. Здесь нет обязательного требования для наличия ключа, но это желательно. Все указанные выше API и есть плагины Гугл карт.